# How to use やんの?

Tags: usage, word-usage

Here is an example from the comic GANTZ. (This should be fair use of the image [at least in the US](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%95%E3%82%A7%E3%82%A2%E3%83%A6%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9) as it's for scholarly commentary.) It's easy to tell that emphasis is being added, and the speaker is marveling at what happened, but it's not clear what it expresses exactly.

[image: example use in sentence]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

「やんの」 ＝ 「やがる」 + 「の」

It is attached to the て-form of a verb to express one's contempt or disdain for another.  It is also used to make fun of a person or his/her action.

> "The fool did/is doing (this or that)!", "Watch that a**hole do ~~!"

Comment: oh, just the regular contraction of everything into ん? Okay :)

Comment: Right, it is the Kanto tough guy speech.